# Can I get a a UK visitor visa if I'm a student and I'm unemployed?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I've been reading this forum and trying to learn as much as I can from other questions. But I still feel like I need to post my questions here.

I'm a 19 years old Equatorial Guinean girl studying in Spain thanks to a Schengen visa. I would like to visit my boyfriend, who is a UK citizen, in the UK during Christmas Holidays for 10 days. Right now I'm studying so I don't have any income because I'm not allowed to work with a student visa. I live with my sister so she is legally and financially in charge of me, if she sponsors my trip, would be enough to show her bank statements?

P.S.
My boyfriend would be my second sponsor because I will stay in his house and he will take care of all my expenses.

Comment: Can you clarify the `I live with my sister so I'm legally and financially in charge of her` part?

Comment: Will you still be studying in Spain next year?

Comment: @JJJ I live in my sister's house in Spain and she pays all my expenses . I have a notarial certificate that says that my sister will support me financially until I finish my engineering degree, which is in 3 years.

Comment: I realize that you've probably considered this already, but since you've lived in Spain since you were twelve, are you not eligible to naturalize as Spanish?  If you could, you would no longer require a visa to go to the UK, of course.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist 
Yes, I will, I have been studying in Spain since I'm 12 years old, and now I'm I'm my first year of college, so I will continue next year

Comment: @phoog Yes, I have, I'm in the process of getting my Spanish citizenship, but is a long process I have already been waiting 1 year and 2 months ,the average time to get Spanish citizenship 2 years .And I haven't met my boyfriend's parents yet and we have been together almost 1 year, so as I Don't know when I will have my citizenship Im consider asking for a visa to visiting them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if [my sister] sponsors my trip, would be enough to show her bank statements?

No.  You have to show your bank statements.  If you do not have a bank account, you should include a statement to that effect.  Even if you have little or no money in your account, and you plan to spend nothing at all of your own funds during the trip, you should show your bank statements.  This is because the visa officer needs to get an accurate picture of *your own circumstances* to judge the likelihood that you will work in the UK, stay there longer than you claim, or otherwise violate the conditions of your admission.  For example, since you are not allowed to work in Spain, the officer will want to see bank statements where any deposits can be shown to have a source other than employment.

Since you say your boyfriend will take care of your expenses, you also need to show his bank statements.  You should also show that you have permission from his landlord (or his parents, or whoever owns the place where he lives) to stay with him.

There are many stories of young adults being denied visas in similar circumstances.  It is a time when people are flexible, and many people of that age seek to move to new places and expand their horizons.  You will therefore want to make it clear that you will be returning to your studies in Spain.